# Python - Apply mean to all columns in dataframe except for the one group by column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a DF with 4 integer columns "NumInstances","Percent","Value" and a text column "Country".

I am trying to have just one row for each country and the mean of all other columns for that row.

How can this be done?

I have tried the below and it does not work:

```
    nsg = nsg .groupby(["Country","NumInstances","Percent"], as_index=False)['Value'].mean()
    nsg = nsg.groupby(["Country","Value","Percent"], as_index=False)['NumInstances'].mean()
    nsg = nsg.groupby(["Country","NumInstances","Value"], as_index=False)['Percent'].mean()
```

Comment: `nsg.groupby("Country").mean()`

Comment: thanks, this results in the dataframe only having 3 column names ['Value', 'NumInstances', 'Percent'] . This is causing errors when I try to call this in a plot later in the script

Comment: Could you add an example of input and output to your question?

Comment: using: list(nsg.columns.values)

Before transform: ['Country','Value', 'NumInstances', 'Percent']

After: ['Value', 'NumInstances', 'Percent']  (no country)

Comment: found the solution. I just needed to add "as_index=False". Thanks!!

Comment: `nsg.groupby(["Country"]).mean()` works for me and keeps Country

Comment: because it was using country as the index